# Split post edit screen into sub-edit screens for users, is this good or bad, and is it possible?

Tags: user-access, post-editor, user-interface

I am working on my user back end access in which users can control a few posts based on post type as well as submit posts in a few other areas (Guides and Encyclopedia entries).

The single post types they have access to have a large amount of meta-data and taxonomies to choose from/enter data into. I was thinking of splitting the post edit screen into separate "sub-edit" screens to divide up the entry input.

1. Is this a good idea?
2. How should I go about setting it up?

Set up Ideas:
2a. I can hide certain parts of the edit screen if I pass a $_GET in the url

OR

2b. I can set up customized edit forms via add_submenu_page function. Which I used when first trying to set up user access from the front end - abandoned this idea as I could not get the WYSIWYG editor to function on the front end.

Any suggestions or insights are greatly appreciated. Thanx!

Comment: I decided against this idea. Worked through it and decided to just alter the admin styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided against the idea. Answered my question for clarity.

Comment: I hope you'll mark this as the Accepted Answer when you can. Also for clarity. :)